# How to build a summary of names in JavaScript source file?

Tags: javascript, python, types, namespaces, brackets

I have a JavaScript source file that is large enough that it will take me a long time to read and understand it all. While there is no magic wand to make that happen, and asking how to do that would be too broad for this site, I am looking for specific ways to get a better understanding of the code.

In this question, I am asking **how to change the code below to build a summary that shows each name in the namespace(s)**. I'll accept implementations in other languages, but since I am familiar with Python I have given some example below in Python.

```
path = '/path/to/source.js'

summary = []

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       # logic that gets name
       summary.append([name]) # [name] not name to extend later
```

Comment: You have multiple questions, ask them separately each with a pair of input, output.

Comment: @DaniMesejo I have edited the question. Thanks for your feedback.